# Why do my target labels need to begin at 0 for sparse categorical cross entropy to work?

Tags: python, keras, cnn, categorical-data, sparse

I'm following a guide [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) to implement image segmentation in Keras.

One thing I'm confused about are these lines:

```
# Ground truth labels are 1, 2, 3. Subtract one to make them 0, 1, 2:
y[j] -= 1
```

The ground truth targets are `.png` files with either 1,2 or 3 in a particular pixel position to indicate the following:

```
Pixel Annotations: 1: Foreground 2:Background 3: Not classified
```

When I remove this `-1`, my `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` values come out as `nan` during training.

```
Epoch 1/15
 25/196 [==>...........................] - ETA: 27s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0348 - sparse_categorical_crossentropy: nan
```

Why is this the case? If the possible integer values are 1, 2, 3, why would I need to alter them to begin at 0 to be correctly used?

If I include the `-1`, the training looks correct:

```
Epoch 1/15
196/196 [==============================] - 331s 2s/step - loss: 2.0959 - accuracy: 0.6280 - sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 2.0959 - val_loss: 1.9682 - val_accuracy: 0.5749 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.9682
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948673/9435355), it seems to be caused by that the fact that your labels need to be zero indexed as the `argmax` function also return the index based on a zero indexed array.